# Lower bound for expectation of squared log?

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

Is there a (tight) lower bound for $\mathbb{E}[(\log x)^2]$ where $x$ is a non-negative random variable? Jensen's inequality doesn't seem to apply here since the squared of a log isn't convex. Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming $x$ is non-negative?

Comment: Yes, x is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine $X$ takes value $a>0$ w.p. $p_a$ and $\frac{1}{a}$ w.p. $1-p_a$

Then, $\log(X)^2 = \log(a)^2=log(\frac{1}{a})^2$; hence, $E[\log(X)^2]$ is a constant whose value is $\log(a)^2$.

Now, lets look at what we can say just about this special case:

$\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \log(a)^2 = \infty$  and $\lim\limits_{a \to 0} \log(a)^2= \infty$

so even in this special case, the expected value of the squared log of an arbitrary positive rv has no finite bound.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the expectation will not be finitely bounded at the limits, and am looking for a functional form (e.g., of $\mathbb{E}[x]$). To illustrate with a popular example, $\mathbb{E}[-\log x] \geq -\log\mathbb{E}[x]$ by Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You can get one useful lower bound using Jensen's inequality. Using the convexity of $(\cdot)^2$, we obtain, $$\mathbb{E}((\log X)^2)\ge (\mathbb{E}(\log X))^2.$$ For instance, for the example illustrated by @user76844, this lower bound will evaluate to $$(1-2p_a)^2(\log a)^2.$$